# Why can't I use mouse navigation buttons (back and forward) on pcmanfm file explorer on lubuntu?

Tags: mouse, pcmanfm, navigation

I'd like to browse my files with one hand without clicking backspace or alt + arrows or clicking on the arrows on the window... just like in firefox or windows applications...

Comment: the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCManFM#No_%22Previous/Next_Folder%22_functionality_with_mouse_buttons) has a comment on this; they suggest to use [xbindkeys](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xbindkeys/).